# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ViewController: 0x896f180>

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I am getting error when pushing a viewcontroller from another viewcontroller in ios.I have used viewwillappear in secondviewcontroller like this

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    self.navigationItem.title=@"Preview";

}
```

The error may be due to this or some other one.can anyone give suggestion

Comment: Error might in the previous view controller where your pushing the view.

Comment: If you post the code where you are pushing the view then it would be easier to find the error.